# Where is the equivalence between $x = y$ and $y = x$ defined?

Tags: logic, axioms

I have been studying the (very elementary) proof of the theorem that the product of two negative real numbers is a positive real numbers. Now I can follow each step in the proof and see how each step uses the axioms of real numbers numbers "under" the operations addition and multiplication (amazing to me the detail needed). Now, in some steps of the proof, the axioms applied are "reversed", or at least that's how I am reading them. E.g. consider $x·0 = 0$, but in the proof the "reverse" property is used, e.g., $0  = x·0$. So my question (finally) is: if $x = y$ is an axiom, then where is the "property" $y = x$ "defined"? Hopefully that question is clear.

Comment: I’m pretty sure $x=y \iff y=x$ is an axiom according to Peano. **Edit:** Yes it is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)#Basic_properties

Comment: Equality "$=$" is defined to be a symmetric relation. Depending on exactly how the reals have been set up in your case, you will have order axioms, including the trichotomy: $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ exactly one of the following holds: $x<y$, $x=y$, or $x>y$. Now apply this axiom for $y,x\in\mathbb{R}$ to conclude that if $x=y$, then you also have $y=x$.

Comment: Thanks spinosarus and @Jaap. I thought I had read that Wikipedia entry. Obviously not carefully enough. The symmetric property. Thank you. Exactly what I need.

Comment: There are many ways of defining axioms for =, and the choice would be out of the scope of such a proof about real numbers.

Comment: See also [Equality and its axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_i)

Answer (score 1):

Usually $=$ is somewhat of a metatheoretical construct. So $a=b$ is taken as the metatheoretical statement "the mathematical objects $a,b$ are the equal, or the same". Thus this symmetry is not really a mathematical axiom, but one of the fundamental metatheoretical axioms you need to do maths.

This is something that exceeds any mathematical model, be it some logical model, some set model, a categorial model or whatever. No matter what mathematical base model you have, you will always assume this metatheoretical axiom $a=b$ is equivalent to $b=a$.

Comment: To be more specific: $=$ is a metatheoretical concept. You will never find a definition of equality, it is something that is provided from "outside".